# How to establish communication between a python script running on Linux with a .NET C# application running on windows?

Tags: c#, python, .net, linux, cross-platform

I am working on an application that requires me to interface a python script running on linux OS on a virtual machine with a .net c# application having wpf forms running on windows such that that the c# application sends files to the python script for processing. What are my options in light of this setting?

I tried using monodevelop on linux in an effort to run .NET applications but it didn't work out as monodevelop doesn't support wpf forms.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MRPb.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have network connection between machines (local network, host only or Internet) then you could listen for files on python using:

1. UDP
2. TCP
3. SimpleHTTPServer

Then in C# app use:

1. `UDPClient`
2. `TCPClient`
3. `WebClient`

Comment: That was my initial guess to establish client-server communication between the two scripts but would this method work for a virtual machine?

Comment: No problem, just setup a network. What kind of virtual machine do you have?

Comment: I don't have much experience with workstation, but you can refer to [documentation](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_net_configurations_common.html) and setup a virtual network. Host-Only Networking should be the simplest choice, but if you want Internet connection from guest OS, then try bridged.

Answer (score 1):

Use sockets to send the file bytes and the result between them.

Some documentation here:

[C# Sockets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6xa24z5(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Python Sockets](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html)

EDIT: This should work using virtual machines